# When using Holotoolkit keyboard.prefab input in unity system keyboard also shown for Windows Mixed Reality app

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, uwp, keyboard, windows-mixed-reality

I'm using the keyboard prefab with KeyboardInputField UI elements from the MixedRealityToolkit and when I select one of the KeyboardInputFields in a build I'm getting both the keyboard prefab and a system keyboard poping up. An earlier build I made using both of these was not displaying the system virtual keyboard, but I don't know what I could have changed to cause this. I am using unity 2017.2.0p2-MRTP5 and MixedRealityToolkit for Unity 2017.2.1f1. (which is what was suggested by the Microsoft representative I talked to)
I'm creating an immersive experience and have the Unity build type set to D3D not XMAL.

Comment: The hololens pops up a keyboard when selecting a Unity input field now? Nice! Nine months ago, that didn't happen. I would be over the moon and just kill the alternate prefab keyboard and use the system one.

Comment: I found more information on the problem here. It is a reported bug.
https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/1370

Comment: The system keyboard does seem to work now, but I'm not sure that it is reliable. For now I'm going to disable the system keyboard and keep using the prefab.

Answer (score 0):

Your input component actually inherits the class `InputField`  in `namespace: UnityEngine.UI.`

When you activate the action of input, Windows will call the systems built-in keyboard automatically.

Disabling the keyboard is undoable unless you avoid using  `UnityEngine.UI.InputField` Component.

What you can do is edit the script yourself.

Comment: I found a solution in the comments of the bug report in the Mixed Reality Toolkit

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in the bug report on the MixedRealityToolkit

> ivan2007:
> "I am experiencing the same issue with my app.
> Unity documentation says:
>
> > Windows Store Apps: On Universal Windows 10 Apps the touch screen keyboard is only supported in XAML based applications with touch input support.
>
> My app is with Build Type D3D and not xaml so this is the first strange thing.
>
> However since the keyboard is shown we can try to disable the touch input support.
>
> To do this we can define a new BaseInput used by the BaseInputModule where touchSupported is overrided and setted to false.
>
> BaseInputModule has a protected property m_InputOverride that we can use to tell unity to use the new BaseInput.
>
> That said, as a temporary workaround, I made the attached script that can be added to the EventSystem game object of the scene or to another game object (in the latter case you must set the field BaseInputModule with the current input module).
>
> In my case it seems to work (the native keyboard is not shown).
> Unity 2017.3.0f3 with HMD
> Can someone try this workaround so we can be more confident using it?.
> Thank you"

https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/files/1710401/HideUnityTouchScreenKeyboard.zip

https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/files/1713278/HideUnityTouchScreenKeyboardC.4.zip